# Translate Copy / Paste in excel from VBA code to C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop

I have this vba code that i am trying to convert into C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

```
So the code is : 

     Columns("AN:AS").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Columns("AT:AT").Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                Columns("AT:AY").Select
                Selection.Replace What:="ST", Replacement:="TO", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I have look into some solutions but i am keep getting errors.

This is what i have done :

```
      Range source = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)currentSheet.get_Range("AN:AS").Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);
                       Range destination =  currentSheet.get_Range("AT: AT");
                        source.Copy(destination);

      currentSheet.get_Range("AT:AY").Replace("ST", "TO", SearchOrder : 1 , LookAt : 2,  MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: false, ReplaceFormat: false);
                        currentSheet.Application.CutCopyMode = 0;

And i got error at the source variable saying : 

An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Impossible de convertir le type 'bool' en 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'
```

My goal is to transform that code from VBA to C#.

Comment: `get_Range(` should likely be `Range[`

Comment: tried that too. still getting some errors. I don't know if i have a problem with the excel format (xls vs xlsx)? but i definitively tried Range [] and still does not work.

Comment: The `CutCopyMode` is a boolean property but you're assigning an int in your c# code?

Comment: @KostasK. No actually the error is on the first line when i assign source. thanks

Comment: Try to break the source assignment. `source = currentSheet.get_Range("AN:AS");`. Then `source.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);`

Comment: No more error but does not behave the way i want. Is it the good translation of the code from VBA to C# ? @KostasK.

Comment: you are near the solution, so dont use .Copy but use .Insert, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to transform that code from VBA to C#.

that should does the job:

```
        using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


        Excel.Range source = currentSheet.get_Range("AN:AS");
        Excel.Range destination = currentSheet.get_Range("AT:AT");

        destination.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, source.Copy());

        currentSheet.get_Range("AT:AY").Replace("ST", "TO", SearchOrder: 1, LookAt: 2, MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: false, ReplaceFormat: false);

        // avoid to have a message about clipboard before saving the file 
        currentSheet.Application.CutCopyMode = XlCutCopyMode.xlCopy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the response.

This is what work finally for me.

```
      Range source = currentSheet.get_Range("AN:AS");
                source.Select();
                source.Copy();

                Range destination = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)currentSheet.get_Range("AT:AT");

                destination.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);


                Range range_sheet = currentSheet.get_Range("AT:AY");
                range_sheet.Select();
                range_sheet.Replace("ST", "TO", SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, LookAt: XlLookAt.xlPart, MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: false, ReplaceFormat: false);
                currentSheet.Application.CutCopyMode = 0;
```